# JS formulário condicional em checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Estou com algumas duvidas em JavaScript onde preciso adicionar condicional ao seleciona uma CheckBox, não sei nem por onde começar.
Valos lá:
4 checkbox, cada uma com um valor (10$, 20$, 30$, 40$).
Condicionais são:
Se escolhe a opção de 20$ e de 40$, vai dar o valor de 60$, subitrair o valor total por 5$.
Simplificando é isso.

```js
var total = 0;

function opc01(campo) {
  if (campo.checked)
    total += eval(campo.value);
  else
    total -= eval(campo.value);
  document.sistema.total.value = total;
}

var total = 0;

function opc02(campo) {
  if (campo.checked)
    total += eval(campo.value);
  else
    total -= eval(campo.value);
  document.sistema.total.value = total;
}

var total = 0;

function opc03(campo) {
  if (campo.checked)
    total += eval(campo.value);
  else
    total -= eval(campo.value);
  document.sistema.total.value = total;
}

var total = 0;

function opc04(campo) {
  if (campo.checked)
    total += eval(campo.value);
  else
    total -= eval(campo.value);
  document.sistema.total.value = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="" name="sistema">

    Opção 01<input type="checkbox" name="opc1" value="10" onClick="opc01(this)"></br>
    Opção 02<input type="checkbox" name="opc2" value="20" onClick="opc02(this)"></br>
    Opção 03<input type="checkbox" name="opc3" value="30" onClick="opc03(this)"></br>
    Opção 04<input type="checkbox" name="opc4" value="40" onClick="opc04(this)"><br>

    <input type="text" name="total" value=""></br>
    <input type="text" name="final" value=""></br>

  </FORM>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: Evite usar `eval()` seu [uso é desestimulado](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#don.27t_use_eval.21) se quer converter strings em inteiros use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) se quer converter strings em ponto flutuante use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: Quanto a pergunta: *...Se escolhe a opção de 20$ e de 40$, vai dar o valor de 60$, subtrair o valor total por 5$....* e se outros checkbox estiverem selecionados juntos o comportamento é o mesmo?

Comment: @AugustoVasques A intenção é ser variavel... caso usuario escolher a opção de 20$ e 40$ diminuir 10$, se ele escolher a opção 20$ e 30$, diminuir 15$... se ele escolher três opções, diminuir 50$....

Answer (score 1):

eval é extremamente desnecessário pro seu caso, e não deveria ser utilizado em lugar nenhum.

você não precisa de uma função pra cada checkbox, se você tivesse 40 checkbox, reescreveria seu código 40 vezes, não é o ideal nunca.

Faça uma única função que percorra cada input e detecte se ele está marcado ou não, se estiver marcado soma e depois da conferencia subtraia 5

```js
function getTotal()
{
  
  // Seleciona todos os checkbox que possuem o atributo class = somaTotal
  let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("somaTotal");
  
  // Váriavel que será retornada
  let total = 0;
  
  
 // Percorre os objetos selecionados
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkBoxes, checkbox => {

    // confere se o obj específico está marcado
    if(checkbox.checked)
    {
      // Recebe o valor do elemento marcado
      let valor = parseInt(checkbox.value);
      
      // Soma o valor ao total
      total += valor;
    }
    
    
  });
  
  // Retorna o valor total subtraindo 5
  console.log(`O total fica em ${total-5}`);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="" name="sistema">

    Opção 01<input type="checkbox" class='somaTotal' name="opc1" value="10" onClick="getTotal()"></br>
    Opção 02<input type="checkbox" class='somaTotal' name="opc2" value="20" onClick="getTotal()"></br>
    Opção 03<input type="checkbox" class='somaTotal' name="opc3" value="30" onClick="getTotal()"></br>
    Opção 04<input type="checkbox" class='somaTotal' name="opc4" value="40" onClick="getTotal()"><br>


  </FORM>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Legal...
Fiz uma function para cada checkbox por ter que apresentar uma condição para cada variavel... caso a professor escolha a opção 3 e 4 ele ter um calculo diferente, subtraindo outro valor... se escolher opção 2 e 3 ter outro calculo...

Comment: Então dentro de uma única função você vai verificar o checkbox.getAttribute('name') dos elementos que estão marcados e guardar em um array. Depois conferir quem são os elementos que estão no array e a partir dai decidir o que vai ser feito ou não. Volto a repetir, uma função para cada checkbox é o caminho errado. Repare que suas funções possuem exatamente a mesma estrutura, abstrair é importante para melhor escrita de código, boas práticas e ganho de desempenho.